# Python mocking function that isn't called directly

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

In my object, I have several "Loader" functions for different types of data that might require loading. They're stored as:

```py
import foo
import bar

class MyClass
    LOADERS = {
        'foo': {
            'context_manager': False,
            'func': foo.data.loader,
            'kwargs': {'data_orientation': 'columns'}
            },
        'bar': {
            'context_manager': True,
            'func': bar.load_data
            'kwargs': {}
            }
        }

    def load_data(self, load_type, path):
        func = self.LOADERS[load_type]['func']
        kwargs = self.LOADERS[load_type]['kwargs']
        if self.LOADERS[load_type]['context_manager']:
            with open(path, 'rb') as f:
                self.data=func(f, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.data = func(path, **kwargs)
```

This is working very well in practice, but I'm finding it's murder to *test*.

When I write my test:

```py
from mock import MagicMock, patch
import sys

sys.modules['foo'] = MagicMock()
sys.modules['bar'] = MagicMock()

from mypackage import MyClass

@patch('foo.data.loader')
def test_load_foo(mock_loader):
    my_obj = MyClass()
    my_obj.load_data('foo', 'path/to/data')
    mock_loader.assert_called_once()
```

it fails. Called 0 times.

I halfway suspect that it's because it's not being called directly. But that *shouldn't* really matter.

Can anyone offer any suggestions? I'm using pytest as my testing engine, but I've found it plays nicely with mock in the past.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arises because you are trying to patch a function within a *class* attribute as opposed to an *instance* attribute. The behavior is not the same. This does however offer us some flexibility as it is a *class* attribute, thus we can modify the object directly on the class we instantiate in our test.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

from mypackage import MyClass


def test_load_foo():
    key_to_test = "foo"
    mock_loader = MagicMock()
    
    my_obj = MyClass()
    my_obj.LOADERS[key_to_test]["func"] = mock_loader
    my_obj.load_data(key_to_test, 'path/to/data')
    mock_loader.assert_called_once()
```

Instead of trying to patch the function, we modify our objects instance to use the `MagicMock`.

Using this approach I receive the following message:

```
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                

tests/test_mypackage.py .                                                                                                                                 [100%]

======================================================================= 1 passed in 0.01s =======================================================================
```

Comment: Of course. It's obvious when you see it!

Thanks!